# How to fix the webpack bug: "you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type." when I useing webpack to load css files

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I am leaning webpack. However, here comes a bug that "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.", I have checked the webpack.config.js, it is correct.

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
 entry: {
  app: './src/main.js',
  print: './src/print.js'
 },
 devtool: 'inline-source-map',
 devServer: {
  contentBase: 'dist',
  hot: true,
 },
 output: {
  filename: '[name].bundle.js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
 },
 module: {
  rules: [{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: [
    'style-loader',
    'css-loader'
   ]
  }]
 },
 plugins: [
  new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   title: 'Output Management'
  }),
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
 ]
};
```

Additionally, here is my js file and css file:

```js
import './style.css';
```

```css
body {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

And the console log this:

```js
./src/style.css
Module parse failed: D:\FrontEndWorkSpace\webpack-demo\src\style.css Unexpected token (1:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| body {

|  background-color: blue;

| }
```

Additional, I have already installed both style-loader and css-loader, here are my dependencies on my package.json:

```js
  "devDependencies": {
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "csv-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
```

EDIT: For some unknown reasons, it's works.

Comment: Do you have css-loader installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed both css-loader and style-loader

Comment: Is the webpack config you posted the full config? The provided files do not reproduce the error. If it's not the full config, you probably have something in there that causes the error, but you thought it wasn't relevant to include it. It's perfectly fine not to post the full config, but please make sure that the reduced config actually produces the stated error. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and **Verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the loaders you're trying to use from NPM. You should see them in both your package.json file and in your node_modules folder of the project. If you don't see them, you can install them and save them to your dev dependencies in your terminal:

`$ npm install style-loader css-loader --save-dev`

Last bit, I've found this [YouTube video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkEZWD8wbltnRp6nRR8kv97RbpcUdNawY) extremely helpful in getting started with Webpack 2. It's changed a lot in its first couple of years, so relevant references are tricky to separate from the obsolete ones.

Good luck taming the webpack beast!

EDIT: Removed extra stuff.

Comment: I have installed both of them. And incidentally, when I tried your method, the console logs a new error: "Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that do match the API schema."